# あかんと言うには大阪からですか？ to ask "Is the word 'akan' from Osaka?"

Tags: phrase-requests

> あかんと言うには大阪からですか？

How would I ask in Japanese "Is the word 'akan' from Osaka?"

Answer (score 3):

You can ask like

> 「あかん」は大阪弁{おおさかべん}ですか？

or

> 「あかん」は大阪{おおさか}の方言{ほうげん}ですか？

Answer (score 2):

You could simply use 「あかん」とは.  Or to be more specific, you could use 「あかん」という言葉は.